# component cannot find action

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a component that has a text field, like this

```
<div>
    {{input type='text' insert-newline='postMessage' class="form-control" autofocus="true"}}
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value={{room.uid}}/>
</div>
```

the component that have this snippet, lives inside a route called `room`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    this.store.findRecord('room', params.uid);
  }
});
```

to handle the action in the `input`, I created a controller for the room:
`app/controllers/room.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    postMessage(params){
      console.log(params);
    }
  }
});
```

but when I hit enter, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: <chathub-ember@component:chat-room::ember1071> had no action handler for: postMessage
```

I tried to put this action in the route as well and didn't worked

Comment: Is the template code that you posted inside of its own component?

Comment: yes, it is @xcskier56

Comment: Ember confines component actions to the component itself. Try putting the action handler in the component.

Comment: PERFECT! can you post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the room.hbs file,

```
{{my-component myAction='postMessage'}}
```

and then in `my-component.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    postMessage(params) {
      this.sendAction('myAction', params);
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: great. also, how do I get the params of the form in the action? because my `console.log(params)` logs `undefined`

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd expect the params to be the event that is sent, and then you could grab it from there. Try using a different event, like `enter`. I have the exact same setup working with `key-up`. The events you can use are here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_textarea

Comment: For passing params from template to component in action 
{{action "postMessage" params}}
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.7.0/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters